# How to optimize the uses controller in laravel route group?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.documents', 'middleware' => 'permissions:volunteer', 'prefix' => 'admin/documents/', 'namespace' => 'Admin/'], function () {
    Route::get('', ['uses' => 'AdminDocumentsController@index',    'as' => '',         ]);
    Route::get('add', ['uses' => 'AdminDocumentsController@create',   'as' => '.create',  ]);
    Route::post('add', ['uses' => 'AdminDocumentsController@create',   'as' => '.create' 
});
```

How can even optimize this code?
ALSO find namespace but AdminDocumentsController its not look goods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add namespace to the first route group, then remove the Admin from the uses

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.documents', 'middleware' => 'permissions:volunteer', 'prefix' => 'admin/documents/'], function () {
    Route::get('', ['uses' => 'AdminDocumentsController@index',    'as' => '',         ]);
    Route::get('add', ['uses' => 'AdminDocumentsController@create',   'as' => '.create',  ]);
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it AdminDocumentsController, i would call it Documents Controller, since you already have it inside the Admin namespace, so either rename the class, or remove the namespace, you dont want Admin to be a duplicate

Comment: Glad it helped, you can catch these conventions by surfing projects on github and such platorms, good luck :)